# Ajax call impact in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, browser

I'm making an ajax call and it's a big process, so it takes some long time. When the call in process, I cant access any page of the site in new browser tabs or the same browser tab. If I open the site in new window, it loads good. Any one have guess on whats wrong with the ajax call

Comment: What exactly happens? What is displayed instead of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use sessions on the server that processes these requests? For me it looks like a lock on a session. Try using read-only session.

What does your server-side "big process" do? Do you run it in a separate thred, does it use transactions on DB? There might be other reasons to that. Plese try to be more specific.

Might also be that you're using synchronous instead of asynchronous requests.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests